# Some recomendation about KIWI TCMS features

Tags: kiwi-tcms

do you know where to write suggestions for improving KIWI TCMS? Our company works with KIWI TCMS 6.10. and we think the following areas could be improved:

- Search optimization. If I click on Search / Search TestCase, test cases are unnecessarily loaded and it takes a long time. It would be good to change that.
- The ability to edit template of TC body (field Text). Now we have to insert our own template into each TC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Feature request should be reported via [GitHub](https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi).

Github ticked for [modifiable test case body](https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/957) is already open - feel free to comment & up-vote it.

As for Search optimization feel free to open another ticket on GitHub.